# Reroute iPhone speaker sound to Bluetooth speaker

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

I have to implement one iOS app i.e reroute sound from iPhone speaker to Bluetooth speaker. I have searched and got one sample [link](https://code.google.com/p/ios-coreaudio-example/downloads/list). In this sample whatever you say in the mic, that sound comes from the speaker. But my requirement is I have to reroute the speaker sound to Bluetooth speaker. Still trying to implement it. Any ideas/suggestions could be very grateful.